# Classes and objects (but not ORD)

Tags: foreign-key

I am looking for help laying out a database that stores information similar to a class definition and then also instances of those 'classes' (but not referring to an ORD).  The specific example is that there are types of electronic modules (`AbstractModule`) that have connectors on them (`AbstractConnector`) and a given type of connector will have some number of contacts in it (`AbstractContact`).  This is straightforword, `AbstractContact` has a foreign key to `AbstractConnector` which has a foreign key to `AbstractModule`.  With those tables filled out and linked I have a set of possible electronic modules defined.

But how do I now store an instance of an abstract module?  The additional information is primarily just the connections made to each pin of each connector on the module.  Is it possible to enforce reasonable constraints in the database or is this a case where it must be enforced by the application?  If we just look at the modules and connectors I would expect

`Connector` FK to its `Module`

`Connector` FK to its `AbstractConnector`

`Module` FK to its `AbstractModule`

My concern is that there are two paths from `Connector` to `AbstractModule` (`Connector`>`AbstractConnector`>`AbstractModule` and `Connector`>`Module`>`AbstractModule`) and I don't see how (other than application code) to enforce that they both end up at the same module.  If the answer is just that, use the application, that's fine.  I just want to be sure I'm not overlooking something or horribly mis-designing the database.

Note that it may well not be necessary to have both `Connector` and `AbstractConnector`, but either way I believe the branching and merging foreign key path will still exist.

Thanks for any comments, links, pointers...  I can't even figure out how to tag this.